# Why don't we use the windows-server tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A moderator recently removed the windows-server tag from one of my questions, and I see there are in fact *no* questions currently tagged windows-server.  Why is this?  I've searched meta and couldn't find any discussion on removing or deprecating windows-server.

It *seems* like a useful tag, for questions that are specific to server editions of Windows?

Comment: For the record, I don't *object*, I'm just puzzled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my earlier comments: I was the one who [edited](https://serverfault.com/posts/730376/revisions) [your question](https://serverfault.com/questions/730376) and removed the [windows-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server) tag.

The main reason for that was that the tag popped up in the [new tags](https://serverfault.com/tags?tab=new) overview and as EEAA explained it doesn't really improve upon the well-used version specific tags such as [windows-server-2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012) [windows-server-2008-r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) etc.

Afterwards I converted it to a synonym for  the generic [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag, which already has the following recommendation in the tag-description which is also quite relevant for the Windows Server family operating systems :

> Windows is the brand name for a series of operating systems from Microsoft. Instead of tagging a post "Windows", try to use a more specific tag, like windows-7, windows-xp or windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: OK.  As previously mentioned, I was not aware it was a new tag.  If I'd known, I wouldn't have used it.  (I don't really understand why it is considered undesirable, but that's OK; I'll take your word for it.)

Answer (score 5):

In the vast majority of cases, we prefer to use tag names that include a version number.

As you'll notice, there are well-used version-specific tags for nearly all versions of Windows Server.

Comment: In this case, I believe that all (current) versions are affected.

Comment: In that case the well used generic [tag:windows], which you already used to tag your question, is preferable to creating a new tag.

Comment: @HBruijn: a *new* tag?  OK, that would explain why there were no other questions, and why you removed it; but I certainly didn't *intend* to create a new tag.  How do you tell the difference?

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62591/187745) there's supposed to be a warning when you create a new tag; no such warning was shown.  Perhaps someone else had already created it?  Or perhaps the warning system is malfunctioning?